# Heterogenous Time Series shift() frequency gives NaN

Tags: pandas

Thanks in advance.

I have a DateTimeIndex series, it looks like:

```
Time
2013-01-25 00:00:00.307000    0
2013-01-25 00:00:00.887000    0
2013-01-25 00:00:01.148000    1
2013-01-25 00:00:01.956000    1
2013-01-25 00:00:02.709000    1
```

What I want is a shift to the closest after the next second. So in this case, the series would look like

```
Time
2013-01-25 00:00:00.307000    0
2013-01-25 00:00:00.887000    0
2013-01-25 00:00:01.148000    0
2013-01-25 00:00:01.956000    0
2013-01-25 00:00:02.709000    1
```

When I do it with either .tshift(1, freq='S') or the same with .shift() I get NaN's for the whole series. Is there somewhere I could read up on this or am I going to have to write a function?

Again, thanks in advance.

Comment: What's you end game here, why are you doing this?